An application of Ito's formula with correlated Brownian increments
I am beginning to study (applied) stochastic calculus. I'm unclear on the following calculation which I am attempting to perform. I am attempting to show that if we have $$\begin{cases} dS_1 = a_1(S_1,S_2,t)dt + b_1(S_1,S_2,t) dX_1\\ dS_2 = a_2(S_1, S_2, t) dt + b_2(S_1, S_2, t) dX_2 \end{cases}$$ and $dX_1, dX_2$ are Brownian increments with correlation $\rho$, then if $V$ is a function of $S_1, S_2$ and time, we have $$dV = \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_1} dS_1 + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_2} dS_2 + \frac{1}{2} b_1^2 \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_1^2} dt + \rho b_1 b_2 \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_1 \partial S_2} dt + \frac{1}{2} b_2^2 \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_2^2} dt.$$
I have begun this problem by applying Ito's formula to get the following - $$\begin{gather} dV = \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_1} dS_1 + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_2} dS_2 + \begin{pmatrix} dS_1 & dS_2\end{pmatrix} H_V \begin{pmatrix}dS_1 \\ dS_2\end{pmatrix} \\ = \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_1} dS_1 + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_2} dS_2 + \begin{pmatrix} dS_1 & dS_2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_1^2} dS_1 + \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_1\partial S_2} dS_2\\ \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_1 \partial S_2} dS_1 + \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_2^2} dS_2 \end{pmatrix} \\ = \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} dt + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_1} dS_1 + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_2} dS_2  + \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_1^2} dS_1^2 + 2\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_1 \partial S_2} dS_1dS_2 + \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_2^2} dS_2^2.\end{gather},$$ where $H_V$ is the Hessian of $V$.
In order to proceed I need to calculate the differentials $dS_1^2, dS_2^2$ and $dS_1dS_2$. I know from earlier study that $dS_1^2 = dS_2^2 = dt$. My question is: how can I calculate $dS_1 dS_2$ using the product rule and in particular how does the correlation between the increments come in?

Has my response answered your question, or it still needs some clarification?

The key is to do the Taylor expansion properly (I change the notation slightly, using initially $\delta$ instead $d$. I also highlight in $\color{red}{red}$ the terms in the Taylor expansion that differ to yours):
First, let's define $\delta V$:
$$\delta V := V(S_1(t_0)+\delta S_1, S_2(t_0)+\delta S_2, t_0+\delta t))- V(S_1(t_0), S_2(t_0), t_0))$$
Now let's do a Taylor expansion around zero (i.e. $S_1(t_0), S_2(t_0), t_0)$ ):
$$\delta V=\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} \delta t + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_1} \delta S_1 + \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_2} \delta S_2 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_1^2} \color{red}{\delta S_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_1 \partial S_2} \color{red}{\delta S_1 \delta S_2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_2^2} \color{red}{\delta S_2^2}$$
We ignore all higher order terms (i.e. $\delta t \delta S_1$, $\delta t \delta S_2$ , $\delta t ^2$ etc.), assuming they go to zero as $\delta \to 0$).
The key results I will be using are:
For any finite $\delta t > 0$ and a standard Brownian motion $X_t$:
\begin{align*}
\tag{1}
\delta X_t := X(\delta t) \stackrel{d}{=}\sqrt{\delta t}X
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\tag{2}
\mathbb{E}[\delta X^2] = \mathbb{E}[\delta t X^2]=\delta t
\end{align*}
And as $\delta t \to 0$ we can argue that:
\begin{align*}
\tag{3}
V(\delta X^2) = V(\delta t X^2]=\delta t^2 V(X^2) \to 0
\end{align*}
(the last results is true because $\delta t^2 \to 0$ and $V(X^2)$ = 3 using Moment Generating Function of a Normal distribution)
Now evaluating the terms:
$$\delta S_1^2=(a_1\delta t + b_1 \delta X_1)^2=a_1^2\delta t^2+2a_1b_1\delta t \delta X_1+b_1^2\delta X_1^2$$
Using (1), (2) and (3) above, we can now argue that as $\delta t \to 0$:

$a_1^2\delta t^2 \to 0$
$2a_1b_1\delta t \delta X_1 = 2a_1b_1\delta t \sqrt{\delta t} X_1 = 2a_1b_1\delta t^{\frac{3}{2}}X_1\to 0$
$b_1^2\delta X_1^2 \to b_1^2 dt$ (using the scaling property and computing: $\mathbb{E}[b_1^2\delta X_1^2] = b_1^2\delta t\mathbb{E}[X_1^2] = b_1^2\delta t $, whilst the variance converges to zero, i.e. $V(\delta b_1^2\delta X_1^2) = b_1^2\delta t^2 \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] \to 0$ using (3) above)

So using the above $\delta S_1^2 \to b_1^2dt$
Using the same machinery, we get that $\delta S_2^2 \to b_2^2 dt$. And we can use the same machinery to compute $\delta S_1 \delta S_2$:
$$\delta S_1 \delta S_2 = a_1a_2 \delta t^2 + a_1b_2 \delta t \delta X_1+b_1a_2 \delta t \delta X_1+ b_1 b_2 \delta X_1 \delta X_2$$
Using the results already shown, everything goes to zero except for the last term:
$$b_1b_2\delta X_1 \delta X_2= b_1b_2 X_1(\delta t) X_2 (\delta t) = b_1b_2 \sqrt{\delta}X_1(1) \sqrt{\delta} X_2 (1) = b1b2 \delta t X_1X_2 $$
We know that the variances are (by definition of Brownian motion) $V(X_1(t))=\mathbb{E}[X_1(t)^2]= t$ and $V(X_2(t))=\mathbb{E}[X_1(t)^2]= t$ and the correlation between $X_1(t)$ and $X_2(t)$ is $\rho$, which means that:
$$Cov(X_1(t), X_2(t))=\rho \sqrt{V(X_1)V(X_2)}= \rho t$$
We also know that:
$$Cov(X_1(t), X_2(t)) = \mathbb{E}[X_1(t) X_2(t)]-\mathbb{E}[X_1(t)]\mathbb{E}[X_1(t)] = \mathbb{E}[X_1(t) X_2(t)]=t\mathbb{E}[X_1 X_2] $$
Using the last two equations, we can say that:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1 X_2]=\rho $$
Therefore, the expected value of the cross term $\delta S_1 \delta S_2$ is $b_1b_2\delta t \rho$ which goes to $b_1b_2 \rho dt$ as $\delta t \to 0$. The variance of this term goes to $0$ (using $V( b1b2 \delta t X_1X_2)=b_1^2b_2^2\delta t^2 V(X_1X_1)$ which goes to zero due to $\delta t^2 \to 0$), so this term converges to $b_1b_2 \rho dt$.
So the formula is (after grouping all terms):
$$dV =\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_1}a_1+ \frac{\partial V}{\partial S_2}a_2+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_1^2}b_1^2+\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_1\partial S_2}\rho b_1b_2+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S_2^2}b_2^2\right) dt + b_1\frac{\partial V}{\partial S_1}dX_1 +b_2\frac{\partial V}{\partial S_2}dX_2 $$
